# How to use hook_views_data_alter to display select list on user reference field?

Tags: 7, views

I want to allow administrator to edit user reference field value on the fly when browsing entities list (view as table). In every row select list with user to choose should appear.

Current code:

```
function rpke_document_assign_views_data_alter(&$data) {
    $data['field_data_field_assignee']['applicant_chooser'] = array(
        'real field' => 'field_applicant_target_id',
        'field' => array(
            'title' => t('Applicant chooser'),
            'help' => t('Applicant chooser based on select list. Extends views_handler_field_user_name'),
            'handler' => 'rpke_field_handler_applicant_chooser',
        ),
    );
}
```

field_assignee is custom CCK field add to entity based on node.

When I try to add this field to a view I am getting error:

> Invalid column name 'field_applicant_target_id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could checkout [Editable Views](https://drupal.org/project/editableviews) which let's you create Views where the fields are editable directly. It works with Field API fields which it looks like your field is.

Comment: I need this to be done without additional contribute module, so I created custom solution but without hook_views_data_alter. It's too much pain to work with standard way solution in my case. Views sometimes really sucks...